# fancybox ie9 (or general ie) width issue

Tags: jquery, fancybox

wonder if anyone can help.

Im using fancybox on a wordpress custom template I'm using, I'm lso using the caroufredsel plugin within the fancybox.

Everything is fine, but I can't seem to get ie9 to change the width of the box manually (im basically getting the width of a loaded image from the carousel and resizing to suit)

All fine in firefox etc, but ie just seems to want to use the default iframe width and ignores any manually set widths, I tried a number of things, I also set the doctype correctly as suggested;

I'm using this to test;this a suggestion I tried.

```
$('#boxWrapper').bind('resize',function(){
        $('#boxWrapper').width(0);
        width = $('#boxWrapper').width()+1000;
        parent.$j('#fancybox-wrap').width(width);
        parent.$j('#fancybox-content').width(width);


    });
```

where box wrapper is a an div around al the content on the page within the fancybox.

Any ideas appreciated

Thanks